# TChart with TKnobGauge creates shifted labels at runtime

Tags: delphi, teechart

Following code creates knob with labels shifted to the right:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  _chart := TChart.Create(Self);
  _chart.Parent := Self;
  _chart.Align := alClient;

  _knob := TKnobGauge.Create(Self);
  _knob.ParentChart := _chart;
  _knob.RotateLabels := False;
  _knob.RotationAngle := 180;
end;
```

[image: shifted knob labels]

The same code as DFM produces the right knob.

What could be wrong?

- TeeChart Pro v2015.16.150901 32bit VCL
- Delphi 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in TChart. When I set

```
_chart.Title.Text.Text := 'Some title';
```

labels are on their places.

When I do

```
_chart.Title.Text.Text := '';
```

or

```
_chart.Title.Visible := False;
```

they are shifted.

The reason why the same code in DFM produced the right knob is that the visual designer extends my minimal chart declaration by adding several properties automatically. Among these properties was a chart title too. It is automatically filled by "TChart" text.

Comment: Have you reported this in either their [Bugtracker](http://bugs.teechart.net/) or [VCL Support forum](http://teechart.net/support/viewforum.php?f=3)? If not, please let us know so that someone with a subscription can post it on their forums.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as exactly what is described in the ticket [#1547](http://bugs.teechart.net/show_bug.cgi?id=1547), initially reported [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=16123).
Please, give a try at the workaround described in the ticket:

> I can only workaround by having a small title with only a blank in it.

Comment: Thank you, it is exact the case, but Google didn't find the ticket when I needed it. Google has better connection with StackOverflow. Unfortunately in bug tracker there is no information about bug fixing status, and if fixed then in which version of TChart.

Comment: I could also report another bug with Title: when I clear it, it is stubbornly filled with default "TChart" text.

Comment: The status of the ticket is "confirmed", not "resolved" yet.